# metadata retrieve operation failed: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-error

On executing:
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapipkg -p ./ProjectComponents.xml
I got the error message:
metadata retrieve operation failed: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No package named

The file ProjectComponents.xml is ok - I used it in Workbench to retrieve and it works ok.
Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Case.List_View_237</members>
        <name>ListView</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 1):

sfdx -p refers to a Package Name, such as a Package or Changeset created in the Salesforce org. To use a Package Manifest file, use:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapipkg -k ./ProjectComponents.xml
```

Where `-k` specifies the manifest file.

Comment: YES, you're right! I managed to get it to work.  Also, I _believe_ that the version has to be "34".  Somehow I mucked through it and got it to work.  Thank you for answering!!!